# Get only lines whose value respects range in bash

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed, sh

Guys I've got a text file with this scheme (just few lines of the original 20k lines):

```
Skeet: 120  Mark: 3636  Tatos: 502
Skeet: 190  Mark: 764  Tatos: 468  
Skeet: 210  Mark: 2106  Tatos: 302
Skeet: 305  Mark: 510  Tatos: 1900
```

What i want to do is to print only lines where value of "Skeet" is from 150 to 240. Remember that lines are more than 10k, so it needs to be inserted into a loop to make sure it reads every line.
Desidered output:

```
Skeet: 190  Mark: 764  Tatos: 468  
Skeet: 210  Mark: 2106  Tatos: 302
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{if ($2 >= 150 && $2 <= 240) print}' file.txt
```

For setting the limits through bash variables you could do something similar to what @RavinderSingh13 pointed out:

```
awk -v start=$foo -v end=$oof '{if ($2 >= start && $2 <= end) print}' file.txt
```

Comment: Works. Is it possible to put a variable instead of an integer number?  Like ( $2 > $foo && $2 < $oof )

Comment: it should be `>=150` and `<=240` since OP told it should be from not between, enjoy learning.

Comment: Thanks, missed that.   Updating answer

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked on my system.  Are you sure you set `foo` and `oof` properly?

Answer (score 4):

As per OP if you want to have shell variables and values of comparisons in variables then following could help you:

```
var="Skeet:" ##Shell variable
awk -v val="$var" -v start=150 -v end=240 '$1==val && ($2>=start && $2<=end)'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks to you too. 
I'm thinking on how, awk handles this task: does it supports non-integers numbers, as opposed to bash?

Comment: @Shred, could you please explain your question with examples, could try to help you.

Comment: Just an obvious question, because I thought myself that awk, as bash, doesn't support non-integer values (like 100.04) . When trying solutions proposed by you and @HardcoreHenry I clear my mind